# Как правильно подступится к :before при помощи .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как правильно подступится к `:before`? Вот как я пытаюсь, но оно не работает:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.wpb_wrapper > ol > li:nth-child(1):before').css('content','6!important');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте **data-атрибут**  в необходимых элементах, и манипулируйте им. 
В стилях соответственно, пропишите значением **content** - содержимое созданного data-* атрибута.

**html:**

```
...
 <li data-newcontent="6">что-то</li>
...
```

**css:**

```
.wpb_wrapper > ol > li:nth-child(1):before {
    content: attr(data-newcontent)
}
```

Comment: Всегда забываю про эту фичу)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, из JS изменить стили псевдоэлементов нельзя, так как они находятся вне DOM-дерева страницы.

Можно сделать так:

1. создать еще один класс в css с `:before`, в котором будут все необходимые изменения, если нужно совсем динамически, то можно создать класс в скрипте и прицепить его на страницу;
2. повесить этот класс на элемент.