# Задать для :before стиль через jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Есть ли способ задать в скрипте для :before у кнопки с классом .btn-expand стиль  transform:rotate(360deg); ?
Пробовала просто так сделать, но не работает..

```
$('.btn-expand').live('click', function(event) {
     $(this).css("transform", "rotate(360deg)");
});
```

Или же какой есть другой выход для этого, раз таким способом сделать невозможно

Вот код целиком ->>> https://jsfiddle.net/pdgeatbs/

Comment: уже был такой вопрос: псевдо элементы они на то и псевдо, что к ним нет доступа из javascript

Comment: Из скриптов псевдоэлементы недоступны

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно подступится к :before при помощи .css()](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453453/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-before-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать нужно так:

1) добавляете класс при клике для родительского элемента

2) через css делаете нужные вещи например так:

```
$('.btn-expand').live('click', function(event) {
     $(this).addClass("active");
});

.btn-expand.active:before {
transform :rotate(360deg)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете манипулировать `:before`, потому что псевдоэлементы недоступны из JavaScript. Но вы можете добавить новый класс с `:before`:

CSS:

```
.btn-expand.changed:after { 
   transform :rotate(360deg)
}
```

JS:

```
$('.btn-expand').live('click', function(event) {
     $(this).toggleClass('changed');
});
```